# How to pass an xml of custom object to ASP.NET MVC Action method via fiddler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

I want to test a MVC action method which accpets a custom class parameter via POST (e.g. Book), I have problem passing the parameter via fiddler. Below is my code:

```
 [HttpPost]  
  public ActionResult BookEdit(BookModel bookModel)
  {

            ...
            return View(...);
  }

 public class BookModel
    {
        public BookModel()
        {        
        }

        public BookModel(Book book)
        {
            this.Authors = book.Authors;
        }

        public List<Author> Authors { get; set; }
    }

    public  class Book
    {
        public List<Author> Authors = new List<Author>();
    }

    public class Author
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Below is the xml that is post to the action method

```
    <BookModel>
        <Authors>
            <Author>
                <Name>1</Name>              
            </Author>
<Author>
                <Name>2</Name>
            </Author>
        </Authors>
    </BookModel>
```

When I pass the xml, the parameter to the action method is null.

Any idea?

Comment: Darin's hit the nail on the head, but the other problem you will have is that your XML doesn't describe your model correctly. BookModel > Authors > Author > Name (twice)?

Comment: @Matthew Abbott I rectify it. But still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I pass the xml, the parameter to the action method is null.

Well, that's normal. I can't see any code of yours which would parse this XML into a BookModel object. ASP.NET MVC doesn't do this by default. It does it for JSON, but not XML.

One possibility would be to write a custom Xml value provider as [shown here](http://www.nogginbox.co.uk/blog/xml-to-asp.net-mvc-action-method). Another possibility is a [custom action filter attribute](http://omaralzabir.com/create_rest_api_using_asp_net_mvc_that_speaks_both_json_and_plain_xml/). Yet another one is a custom model binder.

Comment: Thanks. I can use JSON intead, if it supports JSON by default.